# JQuery: on(...) versus bind(...) versus live(...)

Tags: jquery

I came across this yesterday when I found one of the pages I'd made had stopped working. It turned out I was using a newer version of jQuery than on the server, and that the server version didn't support `.on`. I've corrected by using `.bind()` as well as the explicit action functions, ala `click`. I also did some research on my own and read up on function delegation and how `.on` differed from `.bind` in this respect.

But my question is: why is jQuery still supporting all these different ways to essentially do the same thing? When isn't `.on` the preferred / best way to do things? And why didn't they just update `.bind` and/or `.live` to do what `.on` now does? So again, why is jQuery supporting all of these?

Thanks!

-Tom

Comment: All frameworks and libraries tend to still support outdated methods and stuff for a certain time to maintain backwards compatibility. So first those methods get deprecated, later they get removed. If a method is deprecated can typically be seen by a single look into the documentation. Unfortunately few people appear to bother looking into documentations...

Comment: It is because they don't want to completely break peoples projects every time they update their library. Adding a new feature (even if a similar one already exists) won't break any existing code. Removing an existing feature will most likely deter people from upgrading to the latest and greatest version because it will take time to update the current codebase to match the updated library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had situations where using bind("click", function(){}); instead of click(function(){}); I was able to listen for the click before the target element was created. I'm not sure exactly what version of jquery. Its because there are "direct" and "delegated"events (read more at the link below).

Basically, on() is the one being used now, the live() is deprecated and the bind() will be eventually too (probably)

Why? Something about better event delegation, and probably just changing the name to one more obvious. This page explains it well: http://api.jquery.com/on/